# Saving objects on Parse.com in a .net project

Tags: .net, parse-platform

I have a .net project and I am trying to save some data from it on Parse.com
I can't really find a relevant tutorial there, they mostly contain stuff that is related to Win8 (I am working on Win7).
This is a very simple code that should work but for some reason I can't make it work..

```
        public async static void  ParseUpdate()
    {
        ParseClient.Initialize("myAppID", "myDotNetKey");
        ParseObject Price = new ParseObject("Price");
        Price["price"] = 10;
        Price["productName"] = "Water";
        await PriceNotifications.SaveAsync();
    }
```

I am not getting any errors and nothing in the Parse Console so I am surely missing something really small to make it work..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you got the permission to create an object as well? Maybe permissions require you get logged-in.

If this can help you, this is the code of a little project I'm working on and on .NET (C#) actually works pretty fine:

```
private void createObject() {
    ParseObject question = new ParseObject("Questions");
    question["lang"] = mSelectedLang;
    question["question"] = questionText;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) question["answer" + (i + 1)] = answers[i];
    question["enabled"] = true;
    question["from"] = mUser;
    question["skill"] = 1500;
    question["reputation"] = 0;
    question["matter"] = mSelectedMatter;
    question.SaveAsync().Wait();
}
```

No need of actually doing it in an async void, simple as it is.

The main part of my application is made in Android, where I care lot about details. In fact, I would recommend you to do client-side requests like this only when you're making the prototype of your application. Indeed, actually I'm calling a cloud function in the Android app and since the .NET version is limited and private for me and a restricted group, I don't care about such details. (But I will when I'm gonna close permissions).

When things get more serious, you should think having all your functions on the Cloud (also called Cloud Code).

Plus C# (and the .NET itself) is not the language/framework I'd recommend most to make an app with Parse. You are free to do it, but Parse SDK isn't much clear IMHO about async functions and sync ones like it is on Android or on iOS.

About the Cloud thing, keep in mind that your application may be vulnerable to hackers, so always IMHO, you would resolve much of the problem just using lot more the Cloud Code, since queries are issued by the server itself (which has master key) and the code is not stored on users' devices.

Besides, using Cloud Code for editing objects (except maybe the User class itself) lets you the possibility to remove write or even read permissions to normal users, and the Cloud Code lets you make get-set functions to do the job.

Keep in mind that everyone could do reverse-engineering on your app and getting the client api key, and if your database isn't projected as it should be, that could be really dangerous for you.

For example, this is an [article](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/) which discusses about this problem for Push notifications.

Another advantage of using Cloud Code is that if your app is multiplatform you don't have to rewrite every part of your app, and when you have to make an edit (happens often), you don't have to recompile the app and make the users update.

See this other [post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8347310) (1st answer) which discusses about this.